# sqlalchemy, alchimia and create objects from raw query

Tags: python, asynchronous, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using [alchimia](https://alchimia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to use the power of SQLAlchemy asynchronously.

The only problem I am having it's that building objects from the raw query become tedious, is there a way of using the SQLAlchemy *build objects* part of the ORM without actually using the ORM itself ?

For instance, let's say I have a `user` table like in the alchimia dox sample:

```
users = Table("users", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String()),
)
```

and I query it to retrieve all users:

```
result = yield engine.execute(users.select())
```

I'd like to return models instances instead of `dict`, so I have made a simple builder:

```
class BaseModel(object, pythonutil.FancyEqMixin,
                pb.Copyable, pb.RemoteCopy):
    compareAttributes = ('id',)
    tbl = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k, v in arg.items():
                    setattr(self, k, v)

        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, k, v)

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, resource, alias=None):

        assert (isinstance(cls.tbl, sa.Table)), \
            "Model's '.tbl' property must be a sqlalchemy.schema.Table"

        if isinstance(resource, tuple):
            resource = resource[0]
        resource = dict(resource)
        if alias is not None:
            from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
            alias = (alias.name if
                     isinstance(alias, expression.Alias)
                     else str(alias))
        else:
            alias = cls.tbl.name
        rawdata = dict()
        for (k, v) in resource.items():
            if not k.startswith(alias):
                continue
            # remove the alias from the columns name, some tables
            # may have underscores in their name, so count the occurrence
            # of "_" i the alias ( = tablename) and get the string after it
            # e.g. "module_server_module_ipaddr" becomes "module_ipaddr"
            _k = '_'.join(k.split('_')[1 + alias.count('_'):])
            try:
                # try to get the column from table, on fail skip
                cls.tbl.c[_k]
            except KeyError:
                continue
            rawdata[_k] = v

        return cls(**rawdata)

    def update(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, BaseModel), \
            "other should be %r, %r given" % (BaseModel, other)
        for k, v in other.__dict__.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return setattr(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)
```

This object works like a dictionary but have a possibility to be built with raw query data, here a model sample:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    tbl = user_tbl
```

Can I define models like SQLAlchemy ORM does, query the database with `sqlalchemy core` and then, with the queries data, build the models ?